# android - encode & decode string to be defined as a url

Tags: android, string, url, encoding, android-volley

How to encode and decode or parse the string to make it read as url?

I've tried two things:

1. URLencoder.encode
2. Uri.encode

but the response displays error 400

Here, I have attached the code, look at the below

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            try {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Mencari...");
                showDialog();
                jobList.clear();

                String queryEncode = AppConfig.URL_GETJOBS + Uri.encode(query);


  //String queryEncode = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");

//String queryDecode = AppConfig.URL_GETJOBS + URLDecoder.decode(queryEncode, "UTF-8");

                Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit: " + getJobs(queryEncode));
                getJobs(queryEncode);
                homeRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hideDialog();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here response error 400 on logd: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjbgY.png)

Response in postman 200OK (successfull)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YER6K.png)

Comment: You need to add the getobs() method.

Comment: I already added it, but the obtained string is undefined as url

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that **you can´t access to the address with ip 192.168.43.142 because this is the localhost of your computer**.

[image]

if you are using postman to make the same, you are really doing in the same pc where you have already access.

[image]

Comment: I have tried the ip address by taking the data in localhost. Everything works and there are no constraints, it's just that when I take the string to create the url, its response can not accept. I have not known about decoding, encoding or parce in Uri function